# RAILS assets pipeline: `rake assets:clean` downtime (and ways to avoid it)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I wonder if the command `rake assets:clean` on production causes any downtime...

If it causes downtime, can you suggest ways to prevent it? I know that there is an option to avoid downtime when deploying a full version, but I don't want to deploy when I just fix a JavaScript file and I want to force its compiling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rake assets:clean` should be run on your local machine, not on your production machine, so it shouldn't affect downtime at all.

Files on your production machine(s) are overwritten when you push changes, and you won't register changes to your precompiled assets unless you clear out the old ones first.  That is what `rake assets:clean` is for.

Generally speaking, pushing shouldn't cause downtime either, but it can slow down your app depending on your setup.